# ANDROID_STUDIO ERROR help me

Tags: android-studio

i download telegram project from https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram and import to android studio but occur error

**error:**

```
Build command failed. Error while executing 'C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd' with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/LoieForAhmad/Desktop/New folder (7)/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/fat/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\fat\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -n}

Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk    

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

Error:executing external native build for ndkBuild C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk

Build command failed.

Error while executing 'C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd' with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/LoieForAhmad/Desktop/New folder (7)/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/fat/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\fat\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -n}

Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk    

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

Error:executing external native build for ndkBuild C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk

Build command failed.

Error while executing 'C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd' with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/LoieForAhmad/Desktop/New folder (7)/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -n}

Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk    

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

Error:executing external native build for ndkBuild C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk

Build command failed.

Error while executing 'C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd' with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/LoieForAhmad/Desktop/New folder (7)/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -n}

Android NDK: Your APP_BUILD_SCRIPT points to an unknown file: C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk    


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

Error:executing external native build for ndkBuild C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\New folder (7)\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk

Error:(197, 0) *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop. <a href="openFile:C:/Users/LoieForAhmad/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/build/core/add-application.mk">Open File</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is the location of your project.
it should be in a directory without space in its name.(New folder (7) in your case)
Eliminate spaces in your directory name and it error will disappear

Comment: very well tank u;but occur another problem Error:Execution failed for task ':TMessagesProj:processArmv7DebugGoogleServices'.
> File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
   Searched Location: 
  C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\nf\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\src\armv7\debug\google-services.json
  C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\nf\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\src\debug\armv7\google-services.json
  C:\Users\LoieForAhmad\Desktop\nf\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\src\armv7\google-services.json

Comment: you should sign up in firebase for google GCM and after that, you will get a file named "google-services.json" and then you should put it in JNI's parent folder

Answer (score 0):

1. The problem is based on NDK, make sure you have download Android NDK and its properly installed and try again.
2. Restart AS and rebuild the project.
3. For adding the google json go to this page:
   https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin

Comment: i downloaded ndk and  install it

Comment: i read this page but  my problem is for this project because  import it what it structure and i create with which 4 method (firebase or google ..)

Comment: use the Google method.